# addition of strings inside an multidimensional array - php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this. Each array is having a user ID with scores populated dynamically. I want to add all the strings inside the array and have the key as userID

```
array(3) {
  [13702]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [2]=> .....
    ..... more elements
  }
  [13703]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "6"
     .....
    ..... more elements
  }
  [13774]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "7"
    .....
    ..... more elements
  }
}
```

I want to make it like below

```
array(
'13702'=> 13,//this is the sum of strings inside it
'13703'=> 13,
'13774'=> 7,
);
```

Please help

Comment: Any code attempt?

Comment: @GetSet I tried this  `$simplified = array_reduce($pplayerid, 'array_merge', array());
     $simplified = array_map('intval', $simplified);` but i couldn't manage to assign it to id

Comment: Please put  code attempt in the actual post, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for array reduce, a simple `array_map` applying `array_sum` on each sub array should suffice:

```
$result = array_map('array_sum', $array);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!. I was making it worse